# WPF Overridden TabItem style can't click anything

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I'm relatively new to WPF and XAML, and I'm trying to override the style of the TabItems in my TabControl. At the top of my xaml file I have this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" Margin="0,5,0,0" Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True">

                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEE9ED"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

    </Style>
    
</Window.Resources>
```

It applies the style to all TabItems, and that works. It all looks how I want it to. The problem is that now I can't click on any of them. It doesn't look like any of the style guides online have encountered this problem, so it's probably just something really stupid that I'm doing, but I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>`. A `TabItem` with `IsEnabled` set to `False` cannot be selected. Since all non-selected `TabItem`s are disabled by your `Style`, this prevents any of them from being selected.